# Azure Data Lake Gen2 - How do I move files from folder to another folder using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I have provisioned Datalake gen2 and in C# I am looking for an option on how to move a file from one folder to another folder? With blob storage it's simple but with Datalake I am getting confused about which SDK to use and how it can be done in C#

Also, can I use SAS token generated at the container level for authentication?

Comment: Do you mind if renaming the file?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to  move a file from one folder to another folder in Azure Data Lake Gen2, please refer to the following code

```
public async Task<DataLakeFileClient> MoveDirectory
    (DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeFileClient fileClient=
         fileSystemClient.GetFileClient("<file path>");

    return await fileClient.RenameAsync("<new file path>");
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3f8f6c613efe1483b1bf8f33516983cde1995ea1/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/samples/Sample01b_HelloWorldAsync.cs#L604) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#rename-or-move-a-directory)

Besides, we can use the sas token to manage azure data lake gen2 resource. Regarding how to generate sas token, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/7eb88486a9a55c6b3b55596c9b05e9ac15b65626/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/tests/DataLakeTestBase.cs#L284).